# duplicate objects with trig function translations in Maya + Python

Tags: python, trigonometry, maya

I'm trying to create a hexagonal array of spheres around a center sphere in the XY plane using a python loop function (couldn't figure out how to do it using duplicate special).  It should end up looking something like this:

```
  0 0
0  0  0
  0 0
```

Here's my code.  I' getting a syntax error

```
# Error: line 1: invalid syntax #
```

when I call it, though I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with line one.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class Sphere(radius, tx=0, ty=0, tz=0, sx=0, sy=0, sz=0):
    self.diameter = 2*radius

def createSphere(radius, tx, ty):
    newSphere = Sphere(radius=radius, tx=tx, ty=ty)
    return newSphere

def duplicateSphere(wholeSphere):
    for i in range(6, 1, -1):
        createSphere(tx=wholeSphere.diameter*math.cos(2*math.pi/i), ty=wholeSphere.diameter*math.sin(2*math.pi/i))
        # create spheres with projections onto x and y axes as translation params

duplicateSphere(createSphere(1.03))
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: well, `createSphere` takes 3 arguments but you're only passing it 1 in `duplicateSphere(createSphere(1.03))`

Comment: you are also never using the maya.cmds api to create a new sphere... I think you want `cmds.sphere()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first off to answer your question, the `SyntaxError` is caused by improper class instantiation.  class declaration must be separated from the constructor method in python, like so:

```
class Sphere(object):
    def __init__(self, radius, tx=0, ty=0, tz=0, sx=0, sy=0, sz=0):
        self.diameter = 2 * radius
```

Tip: In the maya *script editor* panel, if you enable **History->Show Stack Trace** it will give you a better idea of where the actual error is occurring.

However, there are a couple other issues at play. For one, you are never storing the parameters you pass into the sphere class (except radius, which you are storing implicitly by storing the diameter). You probably wanted:

```
class Sphere(object):
    def __init__(self, radius, tx=0, ty=0, tz=0, sx=1, sy=1, sz=1):
        self.radius = radius
        self.tx = tx
        self.ty = ty
        self.tz = tz
        self.sx = sx
        self.sy = sy
        self.sz = sz
        self.diameter = 2 * radius
```

I changed the scale defaults to 1 instead of 0 so that the default sphere is not invisibly small.

Also, as theodox pointed out, you have a `TypeError` in your `createSphere` method, which takes 3 params (none of them are keyword arguments currently and therefore not optional) and you are only passing in 1.

However, the main issue is that currently you are not actually creating any spheres in maya. If the intention is that your sphere object is an object-oriented wrapper around maya.cmds, you will need it to call `cmds.sphere` somewhere, and you will probably want to `cmds.move()` and `cmds.scale()` it to by your t* and s* values.  If you do all this in the constructor, you could actually then avoid setting instance variables for all the sphere properties if you wanted.

This would look something like this:

```
cmds.sphere(radius=self.radius)
cmds.move(self.tx,self.ty,self.tz)
cmds.scale(self.sx,self.sy,self.sz)
```

Finally, I think your trig is a bit off (you want each iteration to vary by exactly 60° or π/3 radians).  To get the proper angles, I think you want something more along the lines of:

```
import math

for i in range(6,0,-1):
    angle = math.pi * i / 3.0
    distance = wholeSphere.diameter
    tx = distance * math.cos(angle)
    ty = distance * math.sin(angle)
    # ...
```

As a last note, consider looking at an object-oriented solution like [pymel](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/index.html#!) to avoid needing to reinvent the wheel in terms of wrapping maya.cmds commands in objects.

Anyways, applying all these corrections produces something like:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import math

class Sphere(object):
    def __init__(self, radius, tx=0, ty=0, tz=0, sx=1, sy=1, sz=1):
        self.diameter = 2*radius
        self.radius = radius
        self.tx = tx
        self.ty = ty
        self.tz = tz
        self.sx = sx
        self.sy = sy
        self.sz = sz

        cmds.sphere(radius=self.radius)
        cmds.move(self.tx,self.ty,self.tz)
        cmds.scale(self.sx,self.sy,self.sz)

def createSphere(radius, tx=0, ty=0):
    newSphere = Sphere(radius, tx=tx, ty=ty)
    return newSphere

def duplicateSphere(wholeSphere):
    for i in range(6, 0, -1):
        angle = math.pi * i / 3.0
        distance = wholeSphere.diameter
        tx = distance * math.cos(angle)
        ty = distance * math.sin(angle)
        createSphere(wholeSphere.radius, tx=tx, ty=ty)

duplicateSphere(createSphere(1.03))
```